# Django | DetailView conseguir el id para filtrar

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Una clase de DetailView que a la vez lleva una lista de Dispositivos, no se cómo aplicar como filtro la station del DetailView actual "**filter(estacion=self.station.id)**". Actualmente funciona bien sólo que muestra todos los dispositivos en vez de filtrarlos por estación.

**views.py**

```
class StationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Station
    template_name = "station/detail_station.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the Device
        context['device_list'] = Dispositivo.objects.all()
        return context
```

**dispositivo>models.py**

```
class Dispositivo(models.Model):
...
estacion = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
...
```

**station>models.py**

```
class Station(models.Model):
...
```

Comment: `self.estation` es el objeto que gestiona la vista? por otra parte te debería funcionar bien y si te salen todos los dispositivos es porque todos se relacionan esa estación en especifica...

Comment: Dispositivo.objects.all() me muestra todos los dispositivos. self.station self.station.id los he intentado con la intención de coger la estación que muestra el DetailView, incluso en la url se ve estacion/detail_station/35/ pero algo hago mal que no me toma esa id de station. Supongo que la columna estacion del modelo Dispositivo toma como valor la id, que es la que debería utilizar en el filter para filtrar los Dispositivos por la id de Estación. ¿No es así? Gracias Julio Cesar

Comment: Dispositivo.objects.filter(estacion=self.station) devuelve 'StationDetailView' object has no attribute 'station' ¿Qué puede suceder?

Answer (score 0):

Se hace con self.object.id

```
context['device_list'] = Dispositivo.objects.filter(estacion=self.object.id)
```